# Detect request coming from google home using dialogflow

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

How to detect the request coming to dialogflow from google home devices.

For google assistant,Facebook and all, I used the `source` parameter from the `originalRequest` node.

```
{"originalRequest":{"source":"google","data":{"sender":{"id":"3"},"recipient":{"id":"3"},"message":{"mid":"mid","text":"apple iphone 8","seq":3},"timestamp":1522229806857}}
```

But for google home also I am getting the source parameter as **google** itself.

So Is there any parameter to detect the request coming from google home, so that I can change the response accordingly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no.

First - The Assistant is largely the same on all platforms, so you should be asking why you're trying to identify if the user is using an Assistant with a screen vs one without a screen. You should always be targeting voice as the primary interaction method, even for devices with a screen, and supplement it with visuals rather than relying on them.

However, to determine what capabilities the device you're talking with has, you should look at the `originalRequest.data.surface.capabilities` array. This contains an array of objects with a `name` parameter. That parameter lists the capabilities that this specific device can handle. If one of the values is `actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT`, then it supports a screen (ie - it is a mobile device currently. This will likely also be what is set for the Smart Displays.). If this is absent, then it is likely a speaker (the only device currently available that doesn't have a screen).

Comment: Thanks. It helped. Actually using it for to build the carousel card and all in responses for screen output sources.